# Why doesn't Google cache some of the images on my website

Tags: caching

When I check the Google cached pages of my website, it doesn't cache any of my images including the logo of my website, product images and other images. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not have the GoogleBot image cacher in your robots.txt.

One of many solutions from [here](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160640).  It's the official Google Support section for: My images aren't displaying.

Edit:
These actually seem to be for Google Products, but they should cover the same issues.

Here is the full text for your convenience.

> **My images aren't displaying**
>
> **There are a number of reasons why your
>   images may not be displaying**
>
> **Items were recently submitted**
>
> After your items are processed, there's
>   a delay before our server fetches your images. During this period,
>   we'll display an "image not available" message for your items.
>
> **Images are in an unsupported format**
>
> Please make sure that your images
>   are in one of our supported formats (GIF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, BMP or TIF)
>   and their filenames include the appropriate extensions. In addition,
>   to successfully process an image, its associated URL must link to an
>   image file rather than to a script.
>
> **Your image URLs aren't working correctly**
>
> If your image URLs don't
>   work, an image won't be displayed for your product in our listings.
>   Please make sure all your image URLs are working correctly.
>
> **You've included spaces within your image URLs**
>
> Please make sure that
>   there are no spaces within your image URLs. Each space should be
>   replaced with the characters "%20" (without quotes). Otherwise, we'll
>   be unable to crawl your images and your images will not appear on our
>   search applications. For example, instead of the following URL:
>
> http://www.example.com/my picture.jpg
>
> Please use: http://www.example.com/my%20picture.jpg
>
> **A robots.txt file is on your server**
>
> This prevents us from crawling the
>   images on your site. In order for us to access these images, please
>   modify your robots.txt file to allow both user-agents "Googlebot" and
>   "Googlebot-image" to crawl your site. You can do this by adding the
>   following two lines to your file:
>
> User-agent: Googlebot Disallow:
>
> User-agent: Googlebot-image Disallow:
>
> Learn more about the Robots Exclusion Protocol
>
> **Images redirect**
>
> An image link should link directly to an image. If the
>   image link in your data feed redirects to another URL of the image, we
>   won't be able to grab a copy of your image to add to search results.
>   Image URLs that redirect through ASP, PHP, or Cold Fusion scripts will
>   also fail to be fetched.
>
> **Images have HTTP headers**
>
> Every time information is passed through the
>   Internet, it's preceded by a short description generally called a
>   header. If the header information for an image isn't what's expected,
>   the image processor is unable to cache a copy of your image.
>   Typically, headers may only be an issue for images that are
>   dynamically generated. If you don't know if your images are
>   dynamically generated, this most likely isn't the problem.
>
> Two header fields that must be passed are content-type and
>   content-length. The content-type describes the file type you're
>   sending. Two common values for images are "image/gif" and
>   "image/jpeg." The content-length lets us know the file size for an
>   image. A header field that shouldn't be passed is "cache-control." If
>   you choose to add header fields, please make sure they're appropriate
>   for the image.
>
> **Image size is too large**
>
> It's best to include images that are 300x300
>   pixels or a bit larger. This image size allows us to include a
>   non-distorted image in search results and reduces the possibility of
>   overwhelming your server by requesting much larger images.